# How can I remove ENCODE İNFORMATİON from mediainfo for H265 HEVC .mkv?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, metadata, h.265, matroska

I want to know how I can **remove encode settings** from the mediainfo with mkvpropedit or ffmpeg?

İn this post:
[Removing MP4 encoding information](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18227/removing-mp4-encoding-information)
I found this command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -bitexact -map_metadata -1 -bsf:v 'filter_units=remove_types=6' OUTPUT
```

for **only h264 AVC!**

so how can you do this for **h265 HEVC**
What command do i need to use?

*I want to do this by simply **copy**ing the file I **don't** want to **convert** the whole file.*

İ want to remove this:

> cpuid=0 / frame-threads=3 / no-wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=1920x1080 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=2 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / open-gop / min-keyint=23 / keyint=250 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 /  ...

**UPDATE:**
`-c:v libx265 -x265-params no-info=1` this command does work **but** for converting `-c:v libx265` converts. I want to know how I can do this just to simply **copy** `-c copy` the file?

Answer (score 1):

**-x265-params no-info=1**

```
!ffmpeg -y -i http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.mkv -c:v libx265 -x265-params no-info=1 output.mp4
```

would generate MediaInfo as

> Video ID                                       : 1
> Format: HEVC
> Format/Info: High EfficiencyVideo Coding Format
> profile                           : Main@L4@Main
> Codec ID                                 : hev1
> ...
> Writing library                          : x265 2.6:[Linux][GCC 7.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit

**-x265-params no-info=0**

```
!ffmpeg -y -i http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.mkv -c:v libx265 -x265-params no-info=0 output.mp4
```

would generate MediaInfo as

> Video ID                                       : 1
> Format: HEVC
> Format/Info: High EfficiencyVideo Coding Format
> profile                           : Main@L4@Main
> Codec ID                                 : hev1
> ...
> Writing library                          : x265 2.6:[Linux][GCC 7.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
> *Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1173503 / frame-threads=1 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim ...*

Comment: -c:v libx265 does convert the file. How can I copy the file? I want to do this without converting?

Comment: I want to do something like this ```ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -x265-params no-info=1 output.mkv``` Thank you very much bytheway this works for converthing but I don't want to convert the file like I said

Comment: I have no further comments on modifying the ES level info "without transcoding x265" or "by copying ES to the output".

Answer (score 1):

Use `-x265-params log-level=0`

Reference: https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/cli.html#cmdoption-log-level